# Eliminar relaciones de una tabla intermedia en Sequelize

Tags: express, sequelize.js

Estoy haciendo una app sobre Pokemon y ya logre los metodos GET, POST, DELETE y ahora estoy haciendo el metodo PUT. Tengo 2 modelos, Pokemon y Tipos, mi tabla intermedia se llama "PokemonType". Tengo el problema que al actualizar la informacion y cargar nuevos tipos, no se borran de la tabla intermedia sino que se acumulan. Los metodos que estan en la documentacion no me funcionan. Arrojan un error "getTypes is not a function" o "deleteTypes is not a function". Como puedo eliminar esa informacion de la tabla intermedia?

Esta es la funcion que estoy construyendo, todo funciona excepto eliminar los tipos antiguos
[image: Esta es la funcion que estoy construyendo, todo funciona excepto eliminar los tipos antiguos]

Esta es la documentacion de Sequelize que uso
[image: Documentacion de Sequelize]

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucionaste? me funciono con setTypes (setTemperaments porque me toco el PI de Dogs ajajaja) Si bien cuando retorno el objeto modificado en la ruta PUT me figuran los temperamentos/tipos antiguos, cuando disparo otra vez la GET general me figura modificado correctamente. Saludos!!!

```
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
const {id} = req.params;
const {name, img, breed_group, weight, height, life_span, temperaments, origin} = req.body;
try{
    let currentDog = await Dog.findByPk(id, {include: Temperament});
    currentDog?.update(
        {name, img, breed_group, weight, height, life_span, origin}
    );
    
    await currentDog?.setTemperaments(temperaments);
    
    console.log(currentDog);
    res.status(200).json(currentDog);
}
catch(err){
    res.status(400).send(err)
}
```